Rygel Sharing on Kubuntu 24
I have installed rygel and rygel-preferences to stream files on an older media player. Have allowed the player IP with UFW. The player sees the server but only shows Files&Folders and Playlists. No Video, Pictures or Music options.
Why isn't the Videos option there?

What is the question? Please edit and state a clear question and add some details.

Why isn't the Videos option there?

Please edit the question not answer in comments.
